# Windows Phone LongListSelector How to stop manipulation animation

Tags: c#, animation, windows-phone, longlistselector

How can I stop animation in LongListSelector in code?
I can listen event ManipulationStateChanged but how can I set ManipulationState manually?
For example if user scrolled list, ManipulationStateChanged will not happend while animation is not finished.
I want to stop this animation when scroll position = X...
I can read scroll position, but i cant stop animation when i need. Help me please.
Thanks in advance!

**UPD:**

1. Make a Flick gesture on a LongListSelector
2. You see scroll-animation
3. I can stop animation if make a Tap gesture on a List.

Question: how to stop scroll animation in code?

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? There is no way to k ow where the user wants to stop.

Comment: I can read scroll position and I know X. So if(x == scrollPosition) { list.??????; }

Comment: But my question is why are you trying to stop the scrolling?

Comment: I making "magnetic" list where user can "scroll" items 1 by 1 and cant skip items. For example: items height = 400px; users scroll-position is 800px. User makes Flick gesture. When scroll position is 1200 I want to stop scroll-animation.

Comment: No way to set ManipulationState? :`(

Comment: Any reason not to use the [ScrollTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector.scrollto(v=vs.105).aspx)?